# How to write a sed command to extract only the 'select' queries and save the output to CSV

Tags: jenkins, sed

I need to write a script in jenkins to extract the 'select' queries from a sql file file, execute the queries and save the output in a csv file.But I see there is no relationship between line 4 and line 5.Can someone help to merge these two commands

```
dbname=$Database
echo $dbname
echo $PASS
mysql -u root -p$PASS -h alp-uk-stg.cmw7mobxvnye.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com $dbname
sed '/;/G' sql | grep "SELECT" | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/~/g;ta' | tr "~" "\n"|sed "s/\"/\"\"/g;s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g">output.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql ... | xargs sed ...
```

is probably what you're asking for but without sample input and expected output that's just a guess.

Whatever that pipeline of multiple seds+grep+tr is doing could be done more clearly, robustly, and portably with a single awk script btw - ask a new question if you want help with that.

Finally - you should copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about,

Comment: It would be really helfful if you can explain how to do this using a awk script.

Comment: I tried this.  mysql -u root -p$PASS -h alp-uk-stg.cmw7mobxvnye.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com $dbname < sql | grep "SELECT" | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/~/g;ta' | tr "~" "\n" >> output.csv   But getting no output

Comment: OK, well, that's not at all what I suggested in my answer and without knowing what a sample output of `mysql...` is and what you want to do with it and what the expected output of your full pipeline of commands is given that as input, I'm sorry but I can't help you further. Good luck!